# Currency preg_match_all

Tags: regex, preg-match

i need a complicate regex for counting all occurrences of US Dollar amounts.

This must match:

1000$
1000 $
$1000
$ 1000

1.000$
1.000 $
$1.000
$ 1.000

1000 Dollar
1000 US-Dollar
1000 USD

1.000 Dollar
1.000 US-Dollar
1.000 USD

1000,50$
1000,50 $
$1000,50
$ 1000,50

1.000,50$
1.000,50 $
$1.000,50
$ 1.000,50

1000,50 Dollar
1000,50 US-Dollar

1.000,50 Dollar
1.000,50 US-Dollar

*I only need amount between 1.000 and 20.000$ !

Not needed:

300

300$

$20

$21.000

etc*
I will do this later in PHP!

Comment: _"I need only amounty between 1.000 and 20.000$ !"_ - that throws a red flag that regex may not be the best tool for this job

Comment: Ok, then i will do this later in PHP

Comment: Are you saying that you need to actively avoid capturing `$20` or are you saying that `$20` will never be in your data?

Comment: 20$ is in data but I don't need it.